# .NET CORE - OWASP-ZAP PLUGIN - CI/CD -ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/vsts/work/r1/a/owaspzap/report.json

Tags: bash, continuous-integration, powershell-2.0, owasp, cicd

I have been trying to add the zap owasp scanner plugin on azure DevOps,I cant get the Results tab to display

this is the documentation that I am following
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=CSE-DevOps.zap-scanner

https://dzone.com/articles/owasp-zap-security-tests-in-azure-devops-pipeline

the document says the following
"Note: This script contains a Relative path to the repository and folder, the content of the script may change based on the name you specified in your project."

```
PowerShell
1
$XslPath = "$($Env:SYSTEM_DEFAULTWORKINGDIRECTORY)/_Quality/SecurityTesting/OWASPToNUnit3.xslt"
2
$XmlInputPath = "$($Env:SYSTEM_DEFAULTWORKINGDIRECTORY)/OWASP-ZAP-Report.xml"
3
$XmlOutputPath = "$($Env:SYSTEM_DEFAULTWORKINGDIRECTORY)/Converted-OWASP-ZAP-Report.xml"
4
$XslTransform = New-Object System.Xml.Xsl.XslCompiledTransform
5
$XslTransform.Load($XslPath)
6
$XslTransform.Transform($XmlInputPath, $XmlOutputPath)
```

Please see below my YAML source code and the errors.

```
**<filePath>$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/owaspzap/report.html</filePath>**
```

Below is the error from the pipeline

```
 ##[section]Starting: owaspzap
==============================================================================
 Task         : OWASP Zap Scanner
Description  : Utilize the OWASP/ZAP scanner within Azure DevOps
Version      : 1.0.1
 Author       : Doyle Turner, Anthony Turner
 Help         : 
==============================================================================

[command]"C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\chmod.exe" 777 D:\a\1\s\owaspzap
[command]"C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\id.exe" -u root
/usr/bin/id: 'root': no such user
 [command]"C:\Program Files\Docker\docker.exe" run -u "" -v D:\a\1\s\owaspzap:/zap/wrk/:rw owasp/zap2docker-stable zap-baseline.py -t https://MYWEBSITE.azurewebsites.net:80 -J report.json -r report.html
Unable to find image 'owasp/zap2docker-stable:latest' locally
 latest: Pulling from owasp/zap2docker-stable
 docker: image operating system "linux" cannot be used on this platform.
 See 'docker run --help'.
##[error]The process 'C:\Program Files\Docker\docker.exe' failed with exit code 125
 ##[error]ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\a\1\s\owaspzap\report.json'
 ##[section]Finishing: owaspzap
```

Here's my configuration.
YAML

```
trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1



- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'


- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'publish'
    publishWebProjects: true
    arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration) --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    zipAfterPublish: true
    


- task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
  inputs:
    ConnectionType: 'AzureRM'
    azureSubscription: 'owasService'
    appType: 'webApp'
    WebAppName: 'dev-sowasp'
    packageForLinux: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/**/*.zip'

- task: owaspzap@1
  inputs:
    scantype: 'targetedScan'
    url: 'http://mywebsite.azurewebsites.net'
    threshold: '2'

- task: owaspzap@1
  inputs:
    url: 'http://mywebsite.azurewebsites.net'
    aggressivemode: true
    threshold: '1'

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/owaspzap'
    ArtifactName: 'zap results'
    publishLocation: 'Container'

- bash: |
   sudo npm install -g handlebars-cmd

   cat <<EOF > owaspzap/nunit-template.hbs
   {{#each site}}

   <test-run
       id="2"
       name="Owasp test"
       start-time="{{../[@generated]}}"  >
       <test-suite
           id="{{@index}}"
           type="Assembly"
           name="{{[@name]}}"
           result="Failed"
           failed="{{alerts.length}}">
           <attachments>
               <attachment>
                   <filePath>$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/owaspzap/report.html</filePath>
               </attachment>
           </attachments>
       {{#each alerts}}<test-case
           id="{{@index}}"
           name="{{alert}}"
           result="Failed"
           fullname="{{alert}}"
           time="1">
               <failure>
                   <message>
                       <![CDATA[{{{desc}}}]]>
                   </message>
                   <stack-trace>
                       <![CDATA[
   Solution:
   {{{solution}}}

   Reference:
   {{{reference}}}

   instances:{{#each instances}}
   * {{uri}}
       - {{method}}
       {{#if evidence}}- {{{evidence}}}{{/if}}
                       {{/each}}]]>
                   </stack-trace>
               </failure>
       </test-case>
       {{/each}}
       </test-suite>
   </test-run>
   {{/each}}
   EOF
  displayName: 'owasp nunit template'
  condition: always()

- bash: ' handlebars owaspzap/report.json < owaspzap/nunit-template.hbs > owaspzap/test-results.xml'
  displayName: 'generate nunit type file'
  condition: always()
- task: PublishTestResults@2
  displayName: 'Publish Test Results **/TEST-*.xml'
  inputs:
    testResultsFormat: NUnit
    testResultsFiles: 'owaspzap/test-results.xml'
  condition: always()
  
- task: publishhtmlreport@1
  inputs:
   htmlType: 'genericHTML'
   htmlPath: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/owaspzap/report.html'

- task: DockerInstaller@0
  inputs:
    dockerVersion: '17.09.0-ce'
- task: Bash@3
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      chmod -R 777  ./
      docker run --rm -v $(pwd):/zap/wrk/:rw -t owasp/zap2docker-stable zap-full-scan.py -t http://mywebsite.azurewebsites.net -g gen.conf -x OWASP-ZAP-Report.xml -r scan-report.html
      true

- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      $XslPath = "$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/owaspzap/report.html"
      $XmlInputPath = "$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/OWASP-ZAP-Report.xml"
      $XmlOutputPath = "$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/Converted-OWASP-ZAP-Report.xml"
      $XslTransform = New-Object System.Xml.Xsl.XslCompiledTransform
      $XslTransform.Load($XslPath)
      $XslTransform.Transform($XmlInputPath, $XmlOutputPath)
  
- task: PublishTestResults@2
  inputs:
    testResultsFormat: 'NUnit'
    testResultsFiles: '**Converted-OWASP-ZAP-Report*.xml'
    searchFolder: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)'
  
`
```

Comment: You have several PowerShell tasks in your CI recipe, I suspect that those won't run on Linux either. You might need to run this on `windows-latest` instead of `ubuntu-latest`.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is noted in the exception log:

```
 docker: image operating system "linux" cannot be used on this platform.
```

The Azure VM needs to be configured to allow Linux docker containers to run on the VM.
See these links to help you get that installed / provisioned:

[How to Setup Docker Engine Containers on Windows Server Azure/AWS/GCP](https://cloudinfrastructureservices.co.uk/how-to-setup-docker-engine-containers-on-windows-server-azure-aws-gcp/)

[RUN LINUX CONTAINER ON WINDOWS IN AZURE VM](https://netweblog.wordpress.com/2019/10/18/docker-linux-container-on-windows-in-azure-virtual-machine/)